# THREE.JS: Determine if object has been rendered

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a multipart object which, when I make visible, causes about 800ms of delay.  (Quite bad in Virtual Reality), even though it has already been added to the scene.

The WebGL inspector reveals that when this object is first set to visible and rendered, about 1300 new buffers are created.

Is there an API call I can give to THREE.js to determine if an object has had its buffers initialized? Or better, a command to initialize buffers, even without drawing an object?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should try to optimize this object?

Comment: How would I got about that?  The object is nothing special (e.g., no imported model) - just a number of Box Meshes that make up different interface components. You're right though, it does seem a bit more is happening than should be necessary.

Comment: It's tough to say without knowing what all it has to do, but there are many techniques for optimizing 3D content like re-using shaders and geometry and making spite cards.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "multipart object" ? multiple meshes/single mesh

Comment: Multiple meshes -- An Object 3d, with 10 or so object3ds, each with their own plane and cube meshes.